# why does this routine return an array of length 0?

Tags: c++, iostream

everyone, here is a function I wrote to read a user input which is a vector of double of unknown size, the input must terminate when 'enter' is pressed:

```
vector<double> read_array()
{
    vector<double> array_in;

    double el;

    while (!cin.get())
    {
        cin >> el;
        array_in.push_back(el);
    }

    return array_in;
}
```

To illustrate it consider the following code:

```
void init() // the function that calls the read_array function
{
    cout << "Enter array X: " << endl;
    
    vector<double> X = read_array();
    
    int l = X.size();

    cout << l << endl;
}
```

A typical input when promted is:
1(space)2(space)3(space)4(enter)

When enter is pressed, the input terminates, and the variable 'l' is initialised but is equal to 0
However, when the enter key is pressed, the array size is 0. Debugging it makes it look like it never makes it into the loop like that.

The same routine works well if the input value is not an array.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: What is `el` ? why you use it when you deleted ?

Comment: @GhasemRamezani, sorry, i dont quite get your question. i use el to read user input as elements to the array. the way the routine works is like this:
`vector<double> read_array()
{
 vector<double> array_in;

 double el;

 while (cin >> el)
 {
  array_in.push_back(el);
 }

 return array_in;
}`

Comment: I would recommend using [GNU readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) to get your line from your user, then parsing it (perhaps using `std::istringstream`)

Comment: What is the exact actual input you give? The [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) overload you use doesn't work as you probably think it does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, i input "1(space)2(space)3(enter)" as i hit (enter) the input stops, the routine works for non-array types of data

Comment: Which function are you using, the one shown in the question itself, or the one in the comment? They are *very* different!

Comment: It's a massive learning curve, but I use Boost Spirit for all my parsing. (You can read a `std::vector<double>` in one line.)

Comment: Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it, like including the actual input as well as a [mcve]. For example, how do you check the contents or the size of the vector? Where are you doing that?

Comment: Also: what happened before call the function? To deal with line-based input the easiest approach is to read a line into `std::string` using `std::getline(stream, line)` and then parsing the lune using an `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, i am trying to use the one in the question. The one in the comment is an example of a working function, but it implies that the user terminates input with a non-numeric symbol, which is unwanted, i need it to terminate when 'enter' is pressed. I can check the size of the resulting array using array_name.size() function, which returns 0. I editted the question, thanks

Comment: @pomplamoose `while (!cin.get())` What are you *trying* to do with this? Check out the [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) link already posted in another comment to see what it actually does.

Comment: It's very hard to guess what you think that `!cin.get()` does, but it definitely doesn't do that.

Comment: Actually, so far nobody commented on what `!std:cin.get()` actually *does* (and I forgot to mention it in my original answer; fixed now): `std::cin.get()` just gets the next character. If that character is anything but `'\0'` negating it will be `false` and the loop won't be entered. It seems the hope was that it does something like `'\n' != std::cin.peek()` but even that is insufficient as there may be other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you hope `std::cin.get()` does but based on your comment it seems you hope that it somehow deals with end of lines: it doesn't. It simply reads the next character which is unlikely to do you much good. In particular, if the character is anything but `'\0'` negating it will result in the boolean value `false`. That said, the loop should in principle work *unless* you only input a single digit numeric value followed (possibly after space) by a non-digit or the end of the input.

The easiest approach to deal with line-based input is to read the line into a `std::string` using `std::getline()` and then to parse the line using `std::istringstream`:

```
std::vector<double> read_array() {
    std::vector<double> result;
    if (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::istringstream lin(line);
        for (double tmp; std::cin >> tmp; ) {
            result.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As `std::cin` is only involved while reading lines, `std::cin.fail()` won't be set when parsing `double`s fails. That is, you can read multiple lines with arrays of `double`s, each of which can also be empty.

If you don't want to read an auxiliary line, you'll need to understand a bit more about how formatted input in C++ works: it starts off skipping whitespace. As newlines are whitespace you need to rather read the whitespace yourself and stop if it happens to be a newline or non-whitespace. I'd use a function doing this skipping which returns `false` if it reached a newline (which is still extracted):

```
bool skip_non_nl_ws(std::istream& in) {
    for (int c; std::isspace(c = in.peek()); std::cin.ignore()) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::vector<double> read_array() {
    std::vector<double> result;
    for (double tmp; skip_non_nl_ws(std::cin) && std::cin >> result); ) {
        result.push_back(tmp);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This approach has a similar property that `std::ios_base::failbit` won't be set. However, if any of the characters on a line can't be parsed as `double` the bit will set. That way you can detect input errors. The approach using `std::getline()` will just go on to the next line.

Comment: please, explain the line `if (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line))`

Comment: It is an `if`-statement declaring a local variable (`line`) which is used in the expression `std::getline(std::cin, line)` reading a line. If `std::getline()` failed (i.e., it couldn't extract any characters from `std::cin`) the stream returned from `std::getline()` will convert to `false`, otherwise to `true`. The result of `std::getline()` is then only used in the successful case.